# How to append constant value to the display member of combobox in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have following wpf combobox:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cmbCommissionTier" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMember="CommissionValue">
```

In `DisplayMember="CommissionValue"`, CommissionValue is the property which is containing the value say 10. But I want to display 10% in the combobox. How can I append this % to the display member of combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ItemStringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemstringformat.aspx) should work, something like `{}{0}%`.

Comment: can you give me proper syntax as per my example

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite his entire xaml line. Not immediately obvious to people who dont know about string formatting

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `ItemStringFormat` on your combobox -

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cmbCommissionTier"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  DisplayMember="CommissionValue"
                  ItemStringFormat="{}{0}%">
```

Comment: "ItemStringFormat="{}{0}%" is not recognized or not accessible" error I am getting

Comment: Does `ComboBoxEdit` derives from wpf `Combobox`?

Comment: `ItemStringFormat` is a DP in an `ItemsControl` class from which `Combobox` derives from. It should be there. There is problem somewhere else i guess..

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the ComboBox's ItemTemplate as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCommissionTier" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommissionTier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CommissionValue}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="%"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I have already done this. This works fine for dropdown, but what about displaymember property?